# How do I setup springframework on gradle with only using local directories as repositories?

Tags: java, spring, gradle, spring-framework-beans

I'm new to both using gradle and springframework.

How can I use springframework as a gradle plugin without using any external repositories (including a local maven repository.)? i.e. just use dowloaded springframework files, place them on my local directory and tell gradle to reference to them instead.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Gradle will download the dependencies (and nested ones) for you. Without that and manually installing dependencies you will need to hunt the internet for the correct mix and match of versions again.

Answer (score 0):

You may be looking for [Flat directory repository](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/repository_types.html#sec:flat_dir_resolver):

> Some projects might prefer to store dependencies on a shared drive or
>   as part of the project source code instead of a binary repository
>   product.

As an example, in the `build.gradle` add:

```
repositories {
    flatDir {
        dirs 'lib'
    }
    flatDir {
        dirs 'lib1', 'lib2'
    }
}
```

> This adds repositories which look into one or more directories for
>   finding dependencies. Note that this type of repository does not
>   support any meta-data formats like Ivy XML or Maven POM files.
>   Instead, Gradle will dynamically generate a module descriptor (without
>   any dependency information) based on the presence of artifacts.
>   However, as Gradle prefers to use modules whose descriptor has been
>   created from real meta-data rather than being generated, flat
>   directory repositories cannot be used to override artifacts with real
>   meta-data from other repositories. For example, if Gradle finds only
>   jmxri-1.2.1.jar in a flat directory repository, but jmxri-1.2.1.pom in
>   another repository that supports meta-data, it will use the second
>   repository to provide the module.